# Proving bijection is an equivalence relation

Tags: functions, equivalence-relations

If $M = \{A_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a collection of sets. Consider a relation $R$ on $M$ where $ A_mRA_n$ if there exists a bijection from $A_m$ to $A_n$.

Here is my work so far. For symmetry if we assume $A_mRA_n$ then $A_nRA_m$ just by the definition of a bijection (not sure if there needs more to be said). For reflexivity, I am not too sure how I would show that $\forall n, A_nRA_n $, but I have an intuitive idea. But for transitivity I have no clue at all. My question is, how would I go about starting to prove reflexivity and transitivity and is my proof for symmetry fine?

Comment: $A_mRA_n$ is not a bijection, it's a statement which for each $m,n$ is either true or false. $R$ is a relation and $A_mRA_n$ is true iff there *is some* bijection $f\colon A_m\to A_n$.

Comment: If you are proving symmetry, then you assume that $A_m RA_n$, which means there is a bijection $f:A_m \to A_n$. Now show what the bijection from $A_n$ to $A_m$ actually is. Same for transitivity and reflexivity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(1) Symmetry: a bijection is injective and surjective and has an inverse which is also a bijection. So if $\phi: A_n \to A_m$ is a bijection then $\phi^{-1}$ exists and $\phi^{-1} : A_m \to A_n$. So, $A_nRA_m \implies A_mRA_n$

(2) Reflexivity: define $\phi : A_n \to A_n $ as the identity mapping. This is a bijection. So, $A_nRA_n$

(3) Transitivity: If  $\phi: A_n \to A_m$ and  $\psi: A_m \to A_p$ are bijections then their composition  $\psi.\phi: A_n \to A_p$ is a bijection. So, $A_nRA_m$ and $A_mRA_p \implies A_nRA_p$

Answer (score 2):

Bijection and equivalence are different concepts. For example, $x = y \mod 3$ is an equivalence relation, but they are not in bijection. On the other hand, $x = y + 3$ is a bijection, but not an equivalence, just try to replace $y$ with $x$.

Comment: The question has been answered 4 years ago...Also of course bijection and equivalence relation are different concepts, but you obviously didn't read the question...

Comment: Cardinal of bijection function is an equivalence relation, not bijection function itself.